# Flutter: Remove padding in buttons - FlatButton, ElevatedButton, OutlinedButton

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am looking to remove the default margin of the FlatButton but can't seem to set/override it.

[image: buttons with padding]

```
Column(children: <Widget>[
      Container(
          children: [
            FractionallySizedBox(
              widthFactor: 0.6,
              child: FlatButton(
                  color: Color(0xFF00A0BE),
                  textColor: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                  child: Text('LOGIN', style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 4.0)),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(side: BorderSide.none)))),
      Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
          child: FractionallySizedBox(
              widthFactor: 0.6,
              child: FlatButton(
                  color: Color(0xFF00A0BE),
                  textColor: Color(0xFF525252),
                  child: Text('SIGN UP',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Lato',
                          fontSize: 12.0,
                          color: Color(0xFF525252),
                          letterSpacing: 2.0)))))
    ])
```

I've come across things like `ButtonTheme` and even `debugDumpRenderTree()` but haven't been able to implement them properly.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

```
FlatButton(materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,)
```

Comment: You know... that did the trick. Don't think I would've ever come across that. Silly me, looking for margin/padding syntax.

Comment: Firstly I've looked to margin/padding too )))

Comment: I think it should be noted that removing the target tap size is 'generally' not a good practice, because material design has some strict guidelines around sizing of tap targets which the flutter material widgets try to adhere to.

Comment: FlatButton has minimum size 88.0 by 36.0 based on [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlatButton-class.html) so above solution will not work for smaller button, need to wrap inside ButtonTheme. Check @joel-broström answer.

Comment: If you don't want to use ButtonTheme, just add minWidth:0 - this will reduce the default minimum size to 0, used mostly for smaller buttons.

Comment: FlatButton is deprecated.
ElevatedButton that substitutes it has tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap in style

Answer (score 114):

### UPDATE (New buttons)

- #### `TextButton`

  [image]

  ```dart
  TextButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
      minimumSize: Size.zero, // Set this
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero, // and this
    ),
    child: Text('TextButton'),
  )
  ```
- #### `ElevatedButton`

  [image]

  ```dart
  ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      minimumSize: Size.zero, // Set this
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero, // and this
    ),
    child: Text('ElevatedButton'),
  )
  ```
- #### `OutlinedButton`

  [image]

  ```dart
  OutlinedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
      minimumSize: Size.zero, // Set this
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero, // and this
    ),
    child: Text('OutlinedButton'),
  )
  ```

---

You can also use the raw **`MaterialButton`**

```dart
MaterialButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  color: Colors.blue,
  minWidth: 0,
  height: 0,
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  child: Text('Button'),
)
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer as Flutter have updated buttons

Comment: Yup, thanks bro. This ans shoud be accepted. They are useful for many Buttons in Flutter <3

Comment: You should add `tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap`.

Comment: The new buttons aren't any better though so not much of an answer. I was trying to remove the padding from RawMaterialButton to no avail but with MaterialButton the problem is exactly the same.

Answer (score 40):

I find it easier to just wrap the button in a [ButtonTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonTheme-class.html).

Specify the maxWith and height (set to zero to wrap the child) and then pass your button as the child.

You can also move most of your button properties from the button to the theme to gather all properties in one widget.

```
ButtonTheme(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0, horizontal: 8.0), //adds padding inside the button
  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap, //limits the touch area to the button area
  minWidth: 0, //wraps child's width
  height: 0, //wraps child's height
  child: RaisedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('Button Text')), //your original button
);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there anything wrong with my answer or were the others just better?

Comment: Your answer is better. It just covers all the situations similar to this.

Comment: It doesn't resolve my problem. The FlatButton wrapped in Row still has extra padding. And I don't know where it comes from.

Comment: If you can post your code in a gist [https://gist.github.com/] I can take a look!

Answer (score 35):

```
FlatButton(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0) 
)
```

did the trick for me

Comment: FlatButton has minimum size 88.0 by 36.0 based on [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlatButton-class.html) so above solution will not work for smaller button, need to wrap inside ButtonTheme. Check @joel-broström answer.

Comment: Or better `EdgeInsets.zero`

Comment: As @VivekBansal pointed out this solution won't work, joel-brostrom answer does the trick.

Answer (score 32):

Courtesy of [FlatButton introduces phantom padding](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3678) on flutter's git.

If anyone needs a widget with onPressed event without Flutter padding it.

You should use **[InkWell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html)**

```
InkWell(
    child: Center(child: Container(child: Text("SING UP"))),
    onTap: () => onPressed()
);
```

> A rectangular area of a Material that responds to touch.

Answer (score 17):

**Text Button** previously **FlatButton**

To **remove spacing** between 2 TextButton use tapTargetSize
set `tapTargetSize` to `MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap`

To **remove padding**
set `padding` to `EdgeInsets.all(0)`

```js
TextButton(
    child: SizedBox(),
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap
    ),
    onPressed: () {
    print('Button pressed')
    },
),
```

Answer (score 16):

For all those who are wondering on how to `remove the default padding around the text of a FlatButton`, you can make use of **RawMaterialButton** instead and **set the constraints to BoxConstraints()** which will **reset the default minimum width and height of button to zero**.

> **RawMaterialButton** can be used to configure a button that
>   doesn't depend on any inherited themes. So we can customize all default values based on our needs.

Example:

```
RawMaterialButton(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0), // optional, in order to add additional space around text if needed
    child: Text('Button Text')
)
```

Please refer to [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RawMaterialButton-class.html) documentation for further customization.

Answer (score 7):

you can also change the button width by surrounding it with a sized box:

```java
SizedBox(
  width: 40,
  height: 40,
  child: RaisedButton(
    elevation: 10,
    onPressed: () {},
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0), // make the padding 0 so the child wont be dragged right by the default padding
    child: Container(
      child: Icon(Icons.menu),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

Since FlatButton is now deprecated you can use TextButton. So if you want to remove the padding on TextButton, you would do it like this:

`TextButton( style: ButtonStyle(padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.zero))`

Answer (score 0):

wrap your FlatButton inside a container and give your custom width 
eg.

```
Container(
            width: 50,
            child: FlatButton(child: Text("WORK",style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/locationChange'),materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),),
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same thing, There is horizontal padding inside the `RawMaterialButton` Widget I don't need it.

I solved it using this way :

```
RawMaterialButton(
  onPressed: () {
            
  },
  child: Container(
     child: Row(
        children: [
            // Any thing you want to use it. Column or Container or any widget.
        ],
     ),
   ),
),
```