# How do you discard padding in a FlatButton in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have two FlatButtons in a row. The row is a column which is in turn in a container that is used for the padding of the screen. This container has padding of `right:20` and `left:20`. I want my buttons to be 20 in from left and 20 in from the right to keep everything aligned in my column. I know the `FlatButton` widget has default padding and I've tried the solutions in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52628215/remove-padding-in-flutter-container-flatbutton) Changing the buttons to `GestureDectectors` widgets works with alignment but doesn't have a very nice user experience, the area to click is too small maybe. Ideally I'd like to remove the padding of the `FlatButton` on one side left/right depending on which button. Here is my code

```
Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
children: [
    FlatButton(
    child: new Text('SIGN IN',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1),
    onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context, SignInPage(widget.onSignedIn));
    },

    ),
    new FlatButton(
    child: new Text(
        'SIGN UP',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
    ),
    onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context, SignUpPage(widget.onSignedIn));
    },
    ),
]),
```

Comment: I don't get your question. FlatButton has a padding proeprty, did you try that?
Are you actually talking about margins?

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56603646/5744335) answer. I faced a similar issue and made use of **RawMaterialButton**. I hope it helps someone in future.

Answer (score 3):

Now with the deprecation of the FlatButton for TextButton

```
TextButton(
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(padding: EdgeInsets.all(0)),
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use zero padding, for example

```
padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove extra space from around TextButton and OutlineButton which replace FlatButton use this:

```
 style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
     tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use option 'padding: EdgeInsets.only( depends which side u wanna padding )'

```
FlatButton(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right:10.0),
    child: new Text('SIGN IN',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1),
    onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
           context, SignInPage(widget.onSignedIn));
        },

),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SizedBox(
   height: 25,
   child: ElevatedButton(
             onPressed: onPressed,
             style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius:
                   BorderRadius.circular(kDefaultPadding))),
                child: const Text("More"),
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `FlatButton` is now deprecated and you can use `TextButton`.

Even if you set padding to 0, there is still some padding left. To remove it completely you can use `RawMaterialButton` as suggested by @Arshak [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52628215/remove-padding-in-flutter-container-flatbutton/56603646#56603646).

Example:

```
RawMaterialButton(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0), // optional, in order to add additional space around text if needed
    child: Text('Button Text')
)
```

[image]

I know answer is right there but It took me hours to do this. So I thought to add it as answer also.