# Overflow 1.0 pixel on Raisedbutton - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to personalize what's inside a RaisedButton for my home automation project, in with I add different types of text and icons to the Button. but I'm getting an overflow by 1 pixel for some reason.

```
ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 90.0,
                height: 90.0,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.stay_primary_portrait),
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
                            child: Text('Lock'),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
                            child: Text('100%'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

The app: 
[image]

Comment: maybe using a `Wrap` can solve it? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html

Comment: @LoVe I want to use the full size of the button, so my text is ''Glued" to the edge of the button, but it seems that It has a internal spacing, do you know how can I remove it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52628544/9142279

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RaisedButton has some default padding. Fix it by removing the default padding.
This would work perfectly, check it out.

```
     ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 90.0,
            height: 90.0,
            child: RaisedButton(
              // remove the default padding the raised button has 
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(Icons.stay_primary_portrait),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
                        child: Text('Lock'),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
                        child: Text('100%'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

The output looks like this
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUUP7.png)

Comment: Worked Like a Charm, Thx mate!

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out why you get this result but you can use InkWell + Container instead of RaisedButton:

```
ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 90.0,
                      height: 90.0,
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(Icons.stay_primary_portrait),
                              Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
                                    child: Text('Lock'),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
                                    child: Text('100%'),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: I want to use the full size of the button, so my text is ''Glued" to the edge of the button, but it seems that It has a internal spacing, do you know how can I remove it?