# Align FlatButton within a Row

Tags: flutter

I want to align a FlatButton Widget within a row to the top side.

Unfortunately, it seems that there is some kind of a border, that does not allow the FlatButton (**Add +**) widget to move to the top.

The Align widget is working but only minimally. Here is my code:

```
return Container(
            height: 70.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey))),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Designations:',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                          fontSize: 13.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                    child: ButtonTheme(
                      height: 30.0,
                      // child: Container(),
                      child: FlatButton(
                        color: Colors.blueGrey.shade200,
                        onPressed: () {},
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                        child: Text(
                          'Add +',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: try wrapping the FlatButton with expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your FlatButton to remove the default Padding:

```
materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52628215/remove-padding-in-flutter-container-flatbutton)