# Flutter TextButton Remove Padding and Inner Padding

Tags: flutter

I just updated my code in Flutter to use TextButton instead of old `FlatButton`. I can't figure out how to set width and height of a button though.

I got two problems. First one is that I have this icon Button now:

```
TextButton.icon(
    label: Container(),
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black26),
        icon: Icon(Icons.share, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
        onPressed: () {}),
```

which loos like this:
[image]

I can't figure out how to get rid of the padding on the left and the right. Although I did set the padding inside the style to zero.

My Second Problem is a button that I had like this:

```
ButtonTheme(
    materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
    height: 10,
    minWidth: 15,
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5, left: 5),
    child: FlatButton(
      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
      child: <MyChild>,
      onPressed: () {},
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
          side: BorderSide(
              color: condition
                  ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                  : widget.color != null
                      ? widget.color
                      : Colors.black54,
              width: 0.5)),
    ));
}
```

and it looked like this:
[image]

Now I updated my code to this:

```
OutlinedButton(
    style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
      tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, bottom: 0, right: 5, left: 5),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)),
      side: BorderSide(
          width: 0.5,
          color: condition
              ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
              : widget.color != null
                  ? widget.color
                  : Colors.black54),
      primary: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
    ),
    child: <MyChild>,
    onPressed: () {})
```

But it looks like this now:
[image]
The padding on top/bottom is too much but I can't figure out how to minimize it.

Any advice? Thank you!

**Edit:** I tried to use OutlinedButtonTheme but this did not allow me to set a height etc.

Comment: For the second button thing, did you try increasing the BorderRadius value?

Comment: @CodeSadhu yes. `BorderRadius.circular(12.0)` But I already found the solution. I was no padding it was just set minWidth/minHeight.

Comment: Okay cool! Glad you found the solution.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68517702/14517622

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Flutter `TextButton` is the new button. Since Flutter 2.0 FlatButton is deprecated.

Example of how to use this button with custom styles.
This is a back button with an icon.
It has a wide pressable area and alignment to left according to design.

For inner padding just use `Padding` widget in the child property - it gives you consistent style for any String length.

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      minimumSize: Size(50, 30),
      tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft),
  child: Icon(
    CupertinoIcons.back,
    color: Colors.black,
    size: 18,
  ),
),
```

[image]

For those who are curious about `tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,` property - more info is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71841707/7198006

Comment: Setting maximumSize: Size.zero did the trick for me

Answer (score 96):

You need to set three attributes: `minimumSize`, `padding` and `tapTargetSize`

```dart
TextButton(
  onPressed: (){},
  child: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.black54),
  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
    minimumSize: Size.zero,
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
  ),
)
```

**Edit:**

I have added some padding in my code, and it looks good.

```
padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 3.0, 10.0, 3.0),
```

Comment: Thanks. `tapTargetSize` is critical when having a QA team scans every padding pixels >_<

Answer (score 9):

Okay, I just figured it out. One need to set the `minimumSize` attribute.

```
OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
  minimumSize: Size(widthValue, heightValue),
)
```

This was what made my Buttons bigger than I wanted.