# Flutter 2: Remove additional margin from ElevatedButton / TextButton

Tags: flutter, margin

I would like to know how to remove the margin around the ElevatedButton and TextButton.

Here in detail how it looks:

[image: Margin between two buttons]

```
Column(
  children: [
    ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
        },
        child: Text('Login')
    ),

    TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
        },
        child: Text('Login')
    ),
  ],
)
```

How would you do ?

Comment: This is question is duplicated from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52628215/flutter-remove-padding-in-buttons-flatbutton-elevatedbutton-outlinedbutton

Comment: @Mod as you can maybe see there is a difference in the title of the question between mine and the one from your link. Here a link for more info about what is a padding and a margin: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/css-padding-vs-margin/amp/ . Moreover I think it is a bit useless to post this response after it has been asked 6 month ago and already been responded correctly at that time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is the solution :

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {
    },
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap
    ),
    child: Text('Login')
),

TextButton(
    onPressed: () {
    },
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
      minimumSize: Size(0, 0)
    ),
    child: Text('Login')
),
```

tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap

MaterialTapTargetSize:
Configures the tap target and layout size of certain Material widgets.
Changing the value in ThemeData.materialTapTargetSize will affect the accessibility experience.

shrinkWrap:
Shrinks the tap target size to the minimum provided by the Material specification.

See more on the [official flutter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialTapTargetSize-class.html)

Hope this helps! If you have a better solution tell me!

Comment: `minimumSize` seems to be the key to removing the visual margin. Also, `Size.zero` can be used.