# How to reduce the size of ElevatedButton without hardcoding the values

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**I want to reduce the Width and not hardcode the value by specifying minWidth and minHeight, I want it to look same across all the devices.**

```
ElevatedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_sharp),
              label: Text('Plus One'),
            )
```

[image]

Comment: set insets to 0, try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52628215/remove-padding-in-flutter-container-flatbutton

Comment: `reduce the Width`, `without minWidth and minHeight` but `look same across all the devices`, Sorry, but what do you mean by theses? Do you like to have text width sized button?

Answer (score 0):

Use Media Query to use width wisely for your solution which will run the same for small and large screen

```
 Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5, // Will take 50% of screen space
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Go to screen two'),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          )
```

You can apply a similar solution to SizeBox also.

Comment: Its not reducing the Size. I don't know why ..It's wrapped inside the ListView

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        // Icon
        // Text
      ],
    ))
```