# Flutter, how to remove spaces around text in a TextButton?

Tags: flutter

As titled, `padding: EdgeInsets.zero` doesn't seem to work.
[image]

```dart
Container(
  height: 30,
  width: 60,
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.green, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)),
  child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    child: TextButton(
      child: Text('Login', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white)),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle/padding.html

Comment: I did as shown in my code, still doesn't work.

Comment: No, you did not.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand

Comment: What space do you mean exactly? The space that takes up the green part is just because you made the container 30 by 60. What is your desired result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Remove padding in buttons - FlatButton, ElevatedButton, OutlinedButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52628215/flutter-remove-padding-in-buttons-flatbutton-elevatedbutton-outlinedbutton)

Comment: The text Login doesn’t fully shown, I would like to maintain the size of the green box, while making the size of the text inside as big as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment:

> The text Login doesn’t fully shown, I would like to maintain the size of the green box, while making the size of the text inside as big as possible.

You can do that like this. No need for Containers

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text('Login', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
  style: ButtonStyle(
    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green),
    padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.zero),
  ),
),
```

You can also change the minimum size of the widget by adding `minimumSize` to the `ButtonStyle`. For example:

`minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(Size(10, 10)),`

This will make the minimum size 10x10, if your text size is small enough.
But keep in mind that you need to be able to easily press the button too.

Also check this:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Wrap your container in this

```
MediaQuery.removePadding(
  context:context,
  removeTop:true,
  removeBottom:true,
  child: Container(....)
)
```